# openmaptiles - vector files at lower than zoom level 14

Tags: openmaptiles

Is it possible to generate the source vector files at a resolution lower than zoom level 14?
I know you can overzoom, but that doesn't improve the map resolution, it just lets you get closer to the content resolution at ZL14
So, can OpenMapTiles generate vectors for us to create tiles from that goes down to, say, ZL17?

Comment: You should tweak config files. Set MAX_ZOOM in .env, perhaps in imposm3 configs (see layers directory), etc. BTW, size of your files and job times will be increased very, very much. Using Zoom 17 multiplies your needed resources by 64 times.

Comment: UPDATE: I moved the comment to answer bellow

Answer (score 2):

Vector tiles have an internal resolution by default `4096px`.
You can look at vector tiles from max zoom level **14** up to level **18** while having a pixel-perfect location accuracy.

Only if you need a higher location accuracy, it makes sense to generate vector tiles at deeper zoom levels or with a higher internal resolution.

For **OpenMapTiles** follow https://openmaptiles.org/docs/generate/generate-openmaptiles/ and adjust the `MAX_ZOOM` and layer definitions appropriately.

Check also https://openmaptiles.org/docs/generate/custom-vector-from-postgis/.

Comment: Hi,
I find out that from this tutorial we can generate a vector tile mbtile database but I have no idea if I change zoom level from 14 to 20 it works? and it generates zoom levels higher than 14?with details or we must do anything else for this purpose?